# Pyspark convert a standard list to data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The case is really simple, I need to convert a python list into data frame with following code

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([StructField("value", IntegerType(), True)])
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
rdd = sc.parallelize(my_list)
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df.show()
```

it failed with following error:

```
    raise TypeError("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s" % (obj, type(obj)))
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 1 in type <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Your code failed because schema doesn't match the data. As per question linked above.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This solution is also an approach that uses less code, avoids serialization to RDD and is likely easier to understand:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

# notice the variable name (more below)
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# notice the parens after the type name
spark.createDataFrame(mylist, IntegerType()).show()
```

NOTE: About naming your variable `list`: the term `list` is a Python builtin function and as such, it is strongly recommended that we avoid using builtin names as the name/label for our variables because we end up overwriting things like the `list()` function. When prototyping something fast and dirty, a number of folks use something like: `mylist`.

Comment: This is the better answer because it avoids the serialization to `rdd`.

Comment: Nice answer, clear answer.  The last line, the `.show()` makes `df` hold `None`.

Comment: Is there any way to give name to the Datafield (which in this case will be 'value' by default)

Comment: changing the default column name `value` was baffling me as well. I have a workaround for it to just rename it: `tmp_df.selectExpr("value as text")` anyone has a better idea?

Comment: has anyone tried this using millions of rows? I did, and it did not work very well.

Comment: Works ok w/ millions rows
```spark.createDataFrame(range(10000000), "INTEGER").show(5)```

Answer (score 17):

Please see the below code:

```
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    li=[1,2,3,4]
    rdd1 = sc.parallelize(li)
    row_rdd = rdd1.map(lambda x: Row(x))
    df=sqlContext.createDataFrame(row_rdd,['numbers']).show()
```

**df**

```
+-------+
|numbers|
+-------+
|      1|
|      2|
|      3|
|      4|
+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, this works but I'd like to understand what's different between your approach and my approach? In your code you convert each RDD item into a Row and my code didn't do that, is that way my code failed?

Comment: Yup, to read your list into data frame, you have to convert it into row. From where you can  directly read as data frame. Please accept the answer, if issue is resolved.

Comment: You can refer this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.Row-class.html for more details.

Comment: There should be right button below upvote and downvote. Just click on it.