# How to create a pyspark dataframe from multiple lists

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to convert two lists to a pyspark data frame, where the lists are respective columns.

I tried

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
b=[2, 3, 4, 5]
sqlContext.createDataFrame([a, b], schema=['a', 'b']).show()
```

But I got

```
+---+---+---+---+                                                               
|  a|  b| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|
|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+
```

What I really want is this:

```
+---+---+                                                              
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  4|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+
```

Is there a convenient way to create this result?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448473/pyspark-convert-a-standard-list-to-data-frame?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just transpose the lists:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(zip(a, b), schema=['a', 'b']).show()
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about pyspark directly, but I would guess instead of this data structure:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

you need to give it this

```
[[1, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [3, 4],
 [4, 5]]
```

An explanatory way to go from your data structure to what is required is to use numpy to transpose:

```
import numpy as np
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
b=[2, 3, 4, 5]
sqlContext.createDataFrame((np.array([a, b])).T, schema=['a', 'b']).show()
```

Comment: You'll probably want to be doing this if your data is going to be of any substantial size. And you'd likely want to go further and not use lists in the first place, instead having your data live in numpy arrays from the start.

Comment: to add to that, if your data aren't of substantial size, then why use spark at all?

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to [create pyspark dataframe](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/)
Create sparksession

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
```

Create data and columns

```
columns = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
```

Creating DataFrame from RDD

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df= spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
```

the second approach, Directly creating dataframe

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
```