# Filter words from list python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have this small script to filter the words that contain the value of the `liste`

When I do :

It dispaly :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

How can I correct it ?
Thank you

Comment: Hello, you are trying to use a Pyspark Dataframe method (`where()` which is an alias for `filter()`) on a python string. If you want to use `where()` you need to create a pyspark dataframe. If you want to keep this string (I don't think that distributing this string on multiple nodes is necessary), you need to use methods that can be called from strings. Be careful with the name of your variables, sometimes you use the name "list" for `str` objects and that is disturbing.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html

Comment: @CorentinLimier thank you

Comment: How can I convert listeexclure="AIDE_EN;toCCto;tita" to Dataframe ? I tried df = sc.toDF(listeexclure) but it dispaly AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'toDF'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `listeexclure` is just a string. If you want to search a `string` in another `string`, you can do following:

Let's assume you have a `list` like:

```
lst = ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'bac']
filter(lambda k: 'ab' in k, lst)
# Result will be ['ab', 'abc']
```

So you can apply same method in your code, I think. So in your case:

```
filter((lambda k: broadcastMSA in k, listeexclure)
```

I hope it will help

Comment: How can convert listeexclure to a Dataframe spark ?

Comment: @samtou006 I don't really know but, I just searched and found this [Convert list to DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448473/pyspark-convert-a-standard-list-to-data-frame)