# List all notebooks, jobs in databricks and load resultset into a dataframe and a managed table

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Is there a method to list all notebooks, jobs in one workspace in databricks and load those into a managed table within DBFS?

I found a function code in below link

https://kb.databricks.com/python/list-all-workspace-objects.html

However, this does not give list of jobs.
Also mainly need to store the result set into a dataframe , so that we can store the dataframe in a table .

Comment: I think you should go look here to extract job list: https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsList

Comment: Hi Arthur, Thanks for replying.  Actually, I am trying to use the data in a PowerBI report. Hence, thought of developing the code to store the data into a managed table which can be connected with PowerBI. Also mainly need to store the result set into a dataframe , so that we can store the dataframe in a table .

Comment: You can do what you are saying in a notebook. First retrieve jobs through the API, same for objects, then create dataframes from these calls. Then you juste have to write 2 managed table.

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi Arthur, I am unable to create a dataframe from the function call , I am new to PySpark and DataBricks, code taken from below link https://kb.databricks.com/python/list-all-workspace-objects.html

Comment: Any help is appreciated, code is taken from https://kb.databricks.com/python/list-all-workspace-objects.html , need to return all results in appended form from the functions and when calling the function, it should get stored into a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use job rest api [link](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html). You can use below python code for getting all jobs objects within workspace and phrase what information you need from that response. Note: Tested code !!

```
import requests
import json
class BearerAuth(requests.auth.AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
    def __call__(self, r):
        r.headers["authorization"] = "Bearer " + self.token
        return r
response = requests.get('https://databricksinstance/api/2.0/jobs/list', auth=BearerAuth('token')).json()
print(response)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi KarthiKeyan, Yes, I am able to run this code and getting details, how to store the result in dataframe, I am new to PySpark and DataBricks

Comment: we can get the required details by phrasing  and write as list in python and convert the python list into dataframe . You ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448473/pyspark-convert-a-standard-list-to-data-frame

Comment: schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("object_type",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("path",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("language",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("object_id", StringType(), True), \
  ]) df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema) df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1,schema=schema) Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the snippet below to automatically parse the json response and put it into a Pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.json_normalize(response["jobs"])
```