# Need to convert list to dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pyspark, zip

I have below code in Python but I need to convert this to pyspark,

```
qm1['c1'] = [x[0] in x[1] for x in zip(qm1['id'], qm1['question'])]
qm1['c1'] = qm1['c1'].astype(str)
qm1a = qm1[(qm1.c1 == 'True')]
```

The output of this python code is

| **question** | **key** | **id** | **c1** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Women | 0 | omen | True |
| machine | 0 | mac | True |

Could someone please help me out on the same as I am a beginner in Python?

Comment: Not sure if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48448473/pyspark-convert-a-standard-list-to-data-frame

Comment: I tried already but it did not work

Comment: @user3318064 That's not the proper question to ask. Please show your input, show expected output based on that, and we will be able to create a code to do that. Pandas and PySpark do not work the same, you cannot just convert the code from one to the other as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my test test (as your question does not contain any)

```py
df.show()
+--------+---+----+
|question|key|  id|
+--------+---+----+
|   Women|  0|omen|
| machine|  2| mac|
|     foo|  1| bar|
+--------+---+----+
```

and my code to create the expected output :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("c1", F.col("question").contains(F.col("id")))
df.show()
+--------+---+----+-----+
|question|key|  id|   c1|
+--------+---+----+-----+
|   Women|  0|omen| true|
| machine|  2| mac| true|
|     foo|  1| bar|false|
+--------+---+----+-----+
```

then you can simply `filter` on c1:

```
df.where("c1").show()
+--------+---+----+----+
|question|key|  id|  c1|
+--------+---+----+----+
|   Women|  0|omen|true|
| machine|  2| mac|true|
+--------+---+----+----+
```